# Lookup multiple columns and sum their values in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have the following three names which I would like to lookup their names and sum under cell D2.
[image: Spreadhsheet]

The lookup table (Table1)
[image: Lookup table]

Everything I've found online which deals with summing lookup values is to do with summing multiple columns in the lookup table i.e. `=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(D2,Table1,{2,3},0))`.

I'm trying to accomplish the following: `=VLOOKUP(E5,Table1,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(F5,Table1,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP(G5,Table1,2,FALSE)` but wanted to see if there is an easier way possibly with arrays as theis would cause problems when there are hundreds of columns.

I've also tried this with Index/Match but again all the issues I've found online deal with summing columns in the lookup table based on one reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with `SUMPRODUCT`? You could just use for example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Name]=A2:C2)*(Table1[Age]))
```

[image]

Let me know if I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: No, that's perfect thank you. I didn't think of using Table1[Name]=A2:C2 to span across the columns.